# Calling Kotlin/React from javascript

Tags: javascript, kotlin, create-react-kotlin-app

I'm trying to use Kotlin for building my React APP (https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app).
How can I call a function defined in the Kotlin class through the javascript function? How to set the module using create-react-kotlin-app?